# Difference between a = b and b = a?

Tags: java

I have to get something straight. Please tell me if I'm correct:

```
String a;
String b;
```

a = b means that b takes the value of a?

And

b = a means that a takes the value of b?

I'm awkwardly confused about this & I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: ah...it's the other way round.If the value of b is 5 and then you do a=b, the value of a is also now 5

Comment: In Java, does `a=b` mean that a gets the *value* of b, or a gets a pointer to the *same object* as b?

Comment: Read the symbol `=` as `becomes`

Comment: @Kon Oh. That's a nice way to put it. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanM It depends on whether a and b are primitives (boolean, int, etc) or reference types. But either way, a is getting the value of b, really -- it's just that int he case of reference types, that value is the reference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @yshavit It doesn't depend on whether it is primitive or reference. `a` gets the value of `b`, period. http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Did you read past my first sentence? :)

Comment: @yshavit Yes, but that's the first sentence which shouldn't be there ;)

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Well I think we can both agree that (1) for primitives, a gets the value of b, and (2) for primitives, a does _not_ get a pointer to the same object as b (since no objects are involved). So the answer to Jonathan M's full question, including the second portion about the pointer, is "it depends." :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, `a = b` means "`a` becomes `b`". However, this is only part of the story when we talk about `Object`s (as opposed to primitives). After the assignment both variables or fields reference the same object. When object allows changes (which `String` does not) any changes you perform on `a` take an effect on `b` as well, and vice versa.

This can be illustrated with a simple diagram:

[image: Assignment before and after].

Answer (score 6):

In Java, String a; declaration meaning , a is a reference variable of type String object in memory.

In your case, both a and b are String reference variables.

1) a = b , means a gets the reference of b. if b has any value, it will be assigned to a.

2) b = a , means b gets the reference of a. if a has any value, it will be assigned to b.

It can be easily tested with simple java program if you have started learning in Java.

Java Example:

```
package test;

    public class TestString {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            String a = "Stack";
            String b = "Overflow";
            a = b;
            System.out.println("after [a=b]:" + "a =" + a + ";b=" + b);
            //after this a and b has Overflow as value.
            b = a;
            System.out.println("after [b=a]:" + "a =" + a + ";b=" + b);

        }
    }
```

output:

```
after [a=b]:a =Overflow;b=Overflow
after [b=a]:a =Overflow;b=Overflow
```

Comment: It's a good explanation. If you added some examples it can be better.

Comment: In your point number 2, do you mean to say `b gets the reference of a`?